# Display specific row of an array using pointer and addressing techniques

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures

Hi I am working on a C program that declares a 2 dimensional integer array with N rows and M columns and loads it with consecutive numbers using conventional array element access methods. N and M are equal to 10.  I need display a specific row of the array using this function

```
void showRow(int *arrayName, int rowNumber, int nColsInRow)
```

Then I need to use that function to display the entire array.
I have to do the same thing with the showCol function in my code below.
I have both functions in my code, but I am getting confused on how to implement them.  I appreciate any help that y'all can give.

```
int main(void){

int array[10][10];
int i,j;
int *row0, *row1, *row2, *row3, *row4, *row5, *temp;


int add = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
   for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
   {   
       array[i][j]= add;
       add++;

   }

}


for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i][j]);


    }
    printf(" \n");

}

void showRow(int *array, int rowNumber, int nColsInRow)
{
    row0 = &(array[0][0]);
    row1 = &(array[1][0]);
    row2 = &(array[2][0]);
    row3 = &(array[3][0]);
    row4 = &(array[4][0]);
    row5 = &(array[5][0]);
    row6 = &(array[6][0]);
    row7 = &(array[7][0]);
    row8 = &(array[8][0]);
    row9 = &(array[9][0]);
    row10 = &(array[10][0]);
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d", *(rowNumber + j);

    }

//} 

void showCol(int *array, int colNumber, int nRowsInCol)
{
    col0 = &(array[0][0]);
    col1 = &(array[0][1]);
    col2 = &(array[0][2]);
    col3 = &(array[0][3]);
    col4 = &(array[0][4]);
    col5 = &(array[0][5]);
    col6 = &(array[0][6]);
    col7 = &(array[0][7]);
    col8 = &(array[0][8]);
    col9 = &(array[0][9]);
    col10 = &(array[0][10]);
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d", *(col + j);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: Those can't compile.

Comment: what does nColsInRow represent?

Comment: I know, but I don't know how to make it work

Comment: @Nguaial it represents the number of columns in the row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without changing the signature of the functions, try this code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 void showRow(int *array, int rowNumber, int nColsInRow);
 void showCol(int *array, int colNumber, int nRowsInCol);


 int 
 main(void)
 {

    int array[10][10];
    int i,j;
    int *p;
    int add = 0;

    p = (int *)array; //Set a pointer point to this array.

   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {   
           array[i][j]= add;
           add++;
       }
   }


  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {
         printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
      }
      printf(" \n");
  }
  showRow( p, 2, 3);
  showCol( p, 2, 3);
}

void showRow(int *array, int rowNumber, int nColsInRow)
{
    int *row = &array[rowNumber*10];//row points at the particular row.
    int j;

    for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        printf(" %d", row[j]);

    }

    printf("\n%d\n", row[nColsInRow]);

} 

void showCol(int *array, int colNumber, int nRowsInCol)
{
    int *col = &array[colNumber];  //col points at the particular col of first row.
    int j, n;

  for(j = 0; j < 100; j = j + 10)  //Increment 10 since row size is 10.
  {
    printf(" %d", col[j]);
  }

  n = 10 * nRowsInCol;
  printf( "\n%d\n", col[n]);

 }
```

Explanation:  An integer array is stored in a continuous memory.
              In this case, although it is a 2 dimensional array,
              it stored in 100 continuous unit of 4 bytes. (assuming 
              size of int is 4 in your computer.)

With int pointer, it can point to any index.

e.g.   int *p = &array[58];
       p points at 58th unit of this array.
       Using this concept, now you can do math to get
       particular row or column.

Comment: I don't know why, but for the showRow function the nColsRow is doing nothing to change the code and for the showCol function the colNumber doesn't change anything.  I may be looking at it wrong, but I switched up the numbers to see if it would print the right thing and it was correct, but one of the parameters on each is doing something strange.

Comment: Modified this line:    int *col = &array[colNumber];  //col points at the particular col of first row.
Try it if it works.

Answer (score 1):

I made a change to the showRow function to accept a void pointer.  Then inside of the showRow function I cast it back to 2 dim array.  After that, you can go back to treating just like you would any other 2 dim array.

```
void showRow(void *array, int rowNumber, int nColsInRow)
{
    int (*a)[10] = (int (*)[10]) array;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < nColsInRow; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", a[rowNumber][i]);
    }

}

int main()
{
    int array[10][10];
    int i,j;


    int add = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
       for(j = 0; j < 10; j++)
       {   
           array[i][j]= add;
           add++;

       }

    }

    showRow (&array, 1, 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution.  I never knew this solution existed.  This is a great usage of void *.  But the typecasting can be very tricky. The syntax int (*a)[10] kind of looks like a function pointer of array of 10 that returns int.  But it is not since it does not have (void) in int(*a)[10](void).   So in this case the variable a is pointer of array of 10 of int.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, typecasting in C is tricky.  But, to be fair, lots of things are tricky in C.  :)  As soon as I get enough rep, I'll up vote your answer.